# PCI Simple Communications Controller missing

Tags: drivers

I have Vista Home Prem. on a Presario SR5605F.  I received a message that my PCI Simple Communications Controller needed to be replaced.  I use a Comcast digital modem.  How do I find out what driver I specially need?  The device manager does not give me any info.

Comment: try this? http://www.driveridentifier.com/scan/download.php?item_id=529826194&scanid=B6722234E15342BCB651908E8B3B7F1A&hardware_id=PCI%5CVEN_14F1%26DEV_2F81%26SUBSYS_000014F1

Comment: Message from who or what? What does your modem have to do with anything? There should be plenty of info in Device Manager: you have to open the Properties for any device with an exclamation mark and get the vendor and device id numbers, then use those to search for a driver.

Comment: @kreemoweet PCI simple communications controller is the modem on that particular computer model. Anyway, right clicking>properties on any device should give you the exact driver name.